# Recently unable to create RDS database (and associate with Beanstalk environment)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having problems recently creating a new Amazon RDS database (mySQL) and associating it with an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment. I have done this painlessly in the past for other environments (`simply by going to the environment's configuration tab -> data tier -> "create a new RDS database" -> entering details as needed -> pressing "Save"`).

However, there is now a section at the end requiring me to `"Select the subnets for RDS instances in your Availability Zone"`. I have to tick both of the two subnets detected (which are contained in the default VPC) because I'm required to have a subnet in at least two Availability Zones (despite having selected Single Availability Zone - if that's relevant).

When I click "Apply" I get the error message: `"DBSubnets: Invalid option value: '' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'DBSubnets'): Specify the VPC ID and make sure all subnets exist."`

Any ideas about what I've done wrong? I'm unsure where exactly I'm meant to specify the VPC ID, and why I even have to.

Sorry if I've misunderstood something - I'm fairly new to this stuff. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I had the same issue today. I fixed it by creating a new environment and enabling VPC with a public IP

Comment: but what if you are creating environments from the command line?

Comment: Found it: `eb create --database`

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. @Jad I'll give that a go later - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue as well. They know about it and they are working on a fix (it has been a while though).

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=678379

As noted in comments it works by using the CLI.

```
eb create --database --database.engine mysql --region eu-west-1
```

You can also use eb config to setup a default database.

Comment: This creates a whole new environment. There is currently no way to create and attache an RDS in an existing environment using eb cli